# Regex: negative lookbehind

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

using regex: `(?<!map)\s+.collect\(Collectors.toL`

To match:

1. all 2 line strings where the first line does not have "`map`"
2. And the second line has `collect(Collectors.toL`

Use a negative lookbehind, but as you can see in the link below, the second test is also being matched.

How do we update so as to match as specified above?

https://regex101.com/r/SBJahj/2

Comment: Would [`^(?!.*map).*\n[ \t]*\.collect\(Collectors.toL`](https://regex101.com/r/HLQvXa/1) do what you want?

Comment: Maybe something like `^(?:(?!\bmap\b).)+[\r\n]+\s*\.collect\(Collectors.toL`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You negative lookbehind condition isn't correct because `.map` can have many characters before matching `.collect`. Besides a negative lookbehind with dynamic length isn't supported in most of regex flavors.

You may use this regex with a negative lookahead:

```bash
^(?!\s*\.map).+\n\s*\.collect\(Collectors\.toL
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zSF79T/1)

Here:

- `^`: Start
- `(?!\s*\.map)`: Fail the match if we have `.map` after 0 or more whitespaces
- `.+\n`: Match 1+ chars followed by a line break
- `\s*\.collect\(Collectors\.toL`: Match your desired text in a new line